# Force CharIndex return only 0 if more than one instance is not found?

Tags: sql-server, database, function, sql-server-2005

My Row_1 value is

```
<FeeSize><XMLs><XML Character="1.11" MaxXML="249999.99" Fee="1.60" Cost="1.8" Size="1.8"/><XML Character="251111.11" MaxXML="499999.99" Fee="1.40" Cost="1.7" Size="1.7"/><XML Character="511111.11" MaxXML="999999.99" Fee="1.20" Cost="1.6" Size="1.6"/><XML Character="1111111.11" MaxXML="1999999.99" Fee="1.11" Cost="1.5" Size="1.5"/><XML Character="2111111.11" MaxXML="4999999.99" Fee="1.90" Cost="1.45" Size="1.45"/><XML Character="5111111.11" MaxXML="9999999999999.99" Fee="1.85" Cost="1.425" Size="1.425"/></XMLs></FeeSize>
```

My Row_2 value is

```
<FeeSize><XMLs><XML Character="1.11" MaxXML="249999.99" Fee="1.60" Cost="1.8" Size="1.8"/></XMLs></FeeSize>
```

My requirement is to identify all the starting positions of the string "Character" in the records.

The query I use is

```
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, 1) First_C,
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record)+1) Second_C,
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record)+1)+1) Third_C,
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record)+1)+1)+1) Fourth_C,
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record)+1)+1)+1)+1) Fifth_C,
CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record,CHARINDEX('Character', Record, CHARINDEX('Character', Record)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1) Sixth_C
```

Now I am able to see all the starting positions of 'Character' from Row_1.

Since Row_2 has only one instance of 'Character', I should get the position only at first column First_C. However, I am getting 1st starting position value at third column Third_C and fifth column Fifth_C even though there shouldn't be any.

How do I get '0' for second to six columns for Row_2?

Comment: Why not just use XML functions to parse this

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but the following code will get you the desired result.

```
Use AdventureWorks2017;
Go




Declare @xml1 nvarchar(max)
Set @xml1 ='<FeeSize><XMLs><XML Character="1.11" MaxXML="249999.99" Fee="1.60" Cost="1.8" Size="1.8"/><XML Character="251111.11" MaxXML="499999.99" Fee="1.40" Cost="1.7" Size="1.7"/><XML Character="511111.11" MaxXML="999999.99" Fee="1.20" Cost="1.6" Size="1.6"/><XML Character="1111111.11" MaxXML="1999999.99" Fee="1.11" Cost="1.5" Size="1.5"/><XML Character="2111111.11" MaxXML="4999999.99" Fee="1.90" Cost="1.45" Size="1.45"/><XML Character="5111111.11" MaxXML="9999999999999.99" Fee="1.85" Cost="1.425" Size="1.425"/></XMLs></FeeSize>'

Declare @xml2 nvarchar(max)
Set @xml2 = '<FeeSize><XMLs><XML Character="1.11" MaxXML="249999.99" Fee="1.60" Cost="1.8" Size="1.8"/></XMLs></FeeSize>'

If Object_ID ('tempdb..#Six') is not null Drop Table #Six
Create Table #Six (id int identity (1,1), xml_1 nvarchar(max), xml_2 nvarchar(max))
Insert into #Six (xml_1, xml_2)
Select @xml1, @xml2 UNION ALL
Select @xml1, @xml2 UNION ALL
Select @xml1, @xml2 UNION ALL
Select @xml1, @xml2 UNION ALL
Select @xml1, @xml2 UNION ALL
Select @xml1, @xml2 


Select case 
when id = 1 then charindex('Character',xml_1,1)
when id = 2 and charindex('Character',xml_1,1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)
when id = 3 and charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 4 and charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 5 and charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 6 and charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,charindex('Character',xml_1,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
ELSE 0 end as cascaded_xml1,
case 
when id = 1 then charindex('Character',xml_2,1)
when id = 2 and charindex('Character',xml_2,1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)
when id = 3 and charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 4 and charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 5 and charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
when id = 6 and charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1) <> 0
then charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,charindex('Character',xml_2,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
ELSE 0 end as cascaded_xml2
from #Six
```

What is happening in your code is that the cascaded charindex gets passed in and it is actually = 0 which puts SQL back near the beginning of the string ready to find a new instance of 'Character'. This is rather difficult to get around. The above code will work, I'm sure however, that there is a better way of doing it.